# display a cell value (merged cell) on message box depending on cell selection in another column in ms excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with column A having values A, B, C, D, E. They are merged cells. A1 to A3 with value A. B1 to B3 with value B and so on. Column B has certain description for each value in column A like Apple, aeroplane, ant for value A. banana, bat,ball for value B and so on. Column c blank from c1 to c15. if i select cell c1 or c2 or c3, then A has to be displayed on message box. if i select cell c4 or c5 or c6, then B has to be displayed on message box. if i select cell c7 or c8 or c9, then C has to be displayed on message box. if i select cell c10 or c11 or c12, then D has to be displayed on message box. if i select cell c13 or c15 or c16, then E has to be displayed on message box.

i tried to use the function (=vlookup(A1,$A$1:$B:$15,4,false)). but it does not give me any results. Any help is appreciated (formula or vba).

thanks.

Comment: i have internet access only in a standalone pc in which ms excel or any other ms product is not installed. so, i have given description only and no sample file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a **formula** you could do the following:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&ROW()-MOD(ROW()-1;3))
```

Or the same with **VBA**:

```
MsgBox Range("A" & Selection.Row - (Selection.Row - 1) Mod 3).Value
```

Or if column A is really only the first letter of the words in column B you could of course just go with `UPPER(LEFT(B1))`

Comment: hi,thanks much for your help. but when i used                   MsgBox Range("A" & Selection.Row - (Selection.Row - 1) Mod 3).Value,   it says Run time error '438': object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: =INDIRECT("A"&ROW()-MOD(ROW()-1;3)) worked fine. thanks. but i need it using message box.

Comment: Could you show the full Sub that you are using? And what version of Excel are we talking about?

Comment: i am using excel 2007. i tried to add it to sub button1_click() but gives that error. in vba, under which sub routine do i have to write?

Comment: hi,  sub button1_click()                                                         MsgBox Range("A" & Selection.Row - (Selection.Row - 1) Mod 3).Value                                                               end sub         .  this is what i have used

Comment: Ok. You did not mention you were using buttons. Do you have one button to trigger the MsgBox? Or one button per cell in column C?

Comment: no i need not have buttons. i have just the cells in column C. if i select the first 3 cells by holding control key, or may be even just 1 cell or 2 cells, A should be displayed on the message box. and so on... i tried using WorkSheet_SelectionRange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range) and specifying the range C1:C15 and passing the code MsgBox Range("A" & Selection.Row - (Selection.Row - 1) Mod 3).Value. It shows correctly. but, i dont want it to show for each cell in column C if i am holding ctrl key. how can i do this? Thanks much for your help

Comment: if ctrl key is not pressed, then fine else if ctrl key is pressed,  message box has to wait for the key to be released and display the message only once

Comment: `WorkSheet_SelectionChange` is the right place to catch the selections. But if you want to prevent your MsgBox from popping up while holding the [Ctrl] key you need to check the key states with the GetKeyState API: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/keytest.aspx